# Change IAP type

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I accidentally registered an IAP as nonconsumable, supposed to be consumable.
The app is not yet submitted. But it seems there is no way to edit the type. All we can do now is delete the IAP and create another one, right? The problem here is the IAP product ID cannot be reused so with each mistake like this a new IAP product ID has to be created...

No workaround?

Comment: Yes, delete & add a new one.

Comment: Ok... it is a bit inconvenient, especially in this case cause this app is created by a 3rd party and we have to ask them to change the hardcoded IAP product ID just because of this :-/ We have to run an extra lap. Dohhh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution: delete & add a new one
Note that a new unique product ID has to be used.